# Laptop USB port makes 2V 60Hz sine wave on pwm ports?

Tags: usb, arduino

When I connect my Arduino Mega or Uno to my laptop (HP Pavilion dv6 Windows 7 64 bit) via usb it creates a 2V 60Hz sine wave in the pwm digital pins I am using (2V sine wave when digitalWrite to Low and 5V very noisy pwm when analogWrite is used), and smaller amp sine waves in all the other pins. If I plug either of the boards into a different computer, its totally fine and all the arduino pins give proper 0V or pwm signals. I did not have this problem 2 weeks ago when I ran it, but ran it again today and discovered this problem. The arduino does not appear to have suffered any permanent damage, as it still runs fine on other computers.

The only potentially notable thing I've done in between those two runs was accidentally try to run a motor off an arduino plugged into the laptop that needed more current than the arduino could source ( :$ ). The motor whined but nothing else happened in the second before I unplugged it. Should that be of interest, I only did it on one usb port, and both usb ports are showing this strange sine wave behavior.

Thoughts on what is going on? Is this something I can fix? Is it still safe to program the arduino with my laptop? (Which I can still do, the pins just behave funny until I move it to another computer). I am not able to install software on the other computer (not mine) so cannot do my arduino programming from there.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem between computers and laptops...

My problem was I was running USB power from my computer and a benchtop power supply to some of the digital inputs.

The solution was to cut the trace to isolate USB power from V-in.

This is explained here for [Arduino](http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=22132.0) and here for [teensy3.1.](https://www.pjrc.com/teensy/teensy31.html)

....although I didn't measure the signal, there was an overriding noise that limited the PWM output I could achieve...